# Dynamic Hibernate Mapping Issue

Tags: hibernate

I have created an application using Struts2 and hibernate that perform other operations. However now a change requirement has come up where the user should be able to control the database schema from UI which means the user should have the ability to add new columns on the fly through a user interface.

I am not sure how can I achieve this as updating the database will still leave my entity class untouched.

To illustrate the issue consider the situation: Currently I have my employee table with only two columns : name and roll number. So I create an entity class

```
Class Student{
    int id;
    string name;

    getters and setters
}
```

Using this entity class I can perform CRUD operations in to database.

Now what do I do if I need to have a new column say "age" and and this "age" should also then be created inside the database. And this new column has to be added dynamically from user interface.

Is there a way to update my entity on the fly or is there any other way to achieve it.

Comment: Please post the relevant code, otherwise we can't help you.

Comment: Please show some research work beside your question and read this to ask a good question: 
http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: please check now @meskobalazs

Comment: Well, you *could* add a nullable column into the database without updating the relative JPA or Hibernate entity. It wouldn't raise any error. But obviously, you can't expect having the new field reversed into the .class files without recompiling and redeployng :| This is one of the most stupid requirement EVER seen... probably the birth of the mind of some project manager trying to lower the deployment costs... I can see they: *"Wait a minute, wait a minute... I just had an idea ! What if we..."* :D

Comment: Using `Map` could solve your issue, to some extent.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you cannot do this on the fly, as you need to replace the classes on the application server.

You just need to add the extra property to the entity, then update your DAOs and actions to use the new property.

The dynamic appearance of the form field, has nothing to do with Hibernate nor Struts, you can use JavaScript for that.